# System.Reflection.RuntimeParameterInfo is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, reflection, postsharp

I get the following error when trying to serialize a generic list
"System.Reflection.RuntimeParameterInfo is inaccessible due to its protection level. Only public types can be processed"

here is my code below

```
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<System.Reflection.ParameterInfo>));
            XDocument document = new XDocument();
            using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = document.CreateWriter())
            {
                serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, parameterList);
            }
            return document.Root.ToString();
```

Comment: Well, the error message seems fairly self-explanatory. I don't think you're going to be able to do that. Could you perhaps just serialize the bits you care about?

Comment: how do i go about doing that?

Comment: Could you give more context for this code? If it's used at compile time, there should be a serialization surrogate and that should work.

Answer (score 2):

Not all types are serializable. With a serializer such as `XmlSerializer`, your best approach is to **write a DTO** that has the parts that you are interested in, for example:

```
public class Parameter {
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string TypeName {get;set;}
    public bool ByRef {get;set;} 
}
```

then populate that from the `ParameterInfo`, and serialize *that*. Note that some things are problematic here, for example it would be very inconvenient to serialize a `DefaultValue`, unless you serialize it as a string and parse it back at the receiver.